# SimpleForm: create custom association collection input type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-controls, simple-form

I know that I can create a collection of radio buttons like so:

```
# Slim template
= f.association :requirement, as: :radio_buttons
```

I want to let the user filter the radio buttons using a text field above the radio buttons, so I hacked around a little and came up with the following:

```
label for="filter" Filter
input#filter type="text"
= f.association :requirement, as: :radio_buttons
```

Now I'd like to create this stuff automatically using a custom collection input type:

```
= f.association :requirement, as: :autocomplete
```

So I tried creating a custom input, but I didn't get it to work.

I created the following custom input:

```
# app/inputs/autocomplete_input.rb
class AutocompleteInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionRadioButtonsInput
  # ...
end
```

This lead to the following error:

```
undefined method `collection_autocomplete' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007ffc1d90e9a0>
```

Did you mean?  collection_select

I searched around a bit in the source code of SimpleForm and then tried mimicking what I found for the radio buttons collection input:

```
module SimpleForm
  class FormBuilder
    map_type :autocomplete, to: SimpleForm::Inputs::AutocompleteInput
  end
end
```

But this lead to this rather strange error:

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant AutocompleteInput
```

And now I don't know how to proceed. I have created several custom inputs for simple string and textarea inputs, but with collections I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but there seems to be an open Issue on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1497) that deals with this exact issue. Maybe you can pull what you're looking for from there?

Comment: Do you want an answer to the question how to create a custom input, or want to know how to get the autocomplete working? 'cause the path you're choosing doesn't seem the right solution to the problem you want to solve.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line of CollectionRadioButtonsInput

```
 @builder.send(:"collection_#{input_type}",
      attribute_name, collection, value_method, label_method,
      input_options, merged_input_options,
      &collection_block_for_nested_boolean_style
    )
```

That calls the collection_autocomplete method.

My solution: Don't extend from CollectionRadioButtonsInput. Copy its source and modify it. Not clean but will work.